# Implicit equation and Mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

How to plot implicit equation F(x,y,z)=0 with Mayavi? I tried with

```
import scipy as np
x, y, z = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]
F = x**2/3**2 + y**2/2**2 + z**2/4**2 - 1

from enthought.mayavi import mlab
mlab.contour3d(F)
mlab.show()
```

but I don't get a part of ellipsoid. If I use parametrization and mesh then it's ok, but don't know how to plot it implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [contours = [0]](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#contour3d) to get the surface `F(x,y,z) = 0`:

```
import numpy as np
from enthought.mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]
F = x**2/3**2 + y**2/2**2 + z**2/4**2 - 1
mlab.contour3d(F, contours = [0])
mlab.show()
```

[image]