# draw 3d ellipsoid in vtk or pcl

Tags: vtk

I have equation of a 3D ellipsoid in the format of 
Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + 2Dxy + 2Exz + 2Fyz + 2Gx + 2Hy + 2Iz = 1
and want to plot it in **PCL** (pint cloud library) or **VTK**.

any idea?

Comment: Maybe something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13563782/2870069 ? (Mayavi is some sort of python front end to vtk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a working environment for VTK, you can consider checking [this project](https://github.com/daviddoria/vtkEllipsoidSource), that uses an object called `vtkEllipsoidSource` to draw an ellipsoid. Just compile it, and adjust the parameters to satisfy your equation.